# How to get rid of Ellipsis on Woocommerce [Essential] Theme

Tags: plugins, functions, excerpt, limit, description

As the picture says I am trying to remove the three dots that follow the end of the blue sentence (shown in the photo). I am also trying to increase the numbers of characters it can reveal. Furthermore, for some reason, the blue text shows "&" and "&nspb" symbols at the end of some excerpts, I would like to get rid of these symbols, too.

The website is called: http://biidly.com/

[image]

I have tried adding the following code in the `functions.php` file:

```
/*---------------Removing ellipsis--------------------*/
function wp_new_excerpt($text)
{
    if ($text == '')
    {
        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $text = strip_tags($text);
        $text = nl2br($text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 235);
        $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
        if (count($words) > $excerpt_length) {
            array_pop($words);
            array_push($words, '[asda]');
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_new_excerpt');
```

However, this code has not worked. I am unsure where to go from here.

I have also tried:

```
function wpse_180792_excerpt_more() {
    return '';
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpse_180792_excerpt_more' );
```

However, this code has not worked, either.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes.

Comment: You need to find out what code the theme is using to output that bit of text.

Comment: How do I find that? Sorry, this is my first time working with Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`excerpt_more`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) filter:

```
function wpse_180792_excerpt_more() {
    return '';
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpse_180792_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: I put that in my functions.php page, but the ellipsis is still there. Thank you for trying.